# Using Google Maps & Earth data in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-earth

I'm writing a flight simulator in C# using NeoAxis. It will be very helpful to get somehow real world maps (detailed) + height data to generate heightmaps. What will be good solution in this case? Can I get this data from Google Earth api/Maps api? If not what URLs will be helpful to do research in this direction?

Comment: I seem to recall some license issues with using exported data from Google Earth. They have to license the content from the providers, which you would have to do, as well, if you wanted to redistribute it.

Comment: Anyway, google earth already has a [flight sim feature](http://earth.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=22385)

Comment: So, maybe there are some alternatives?